# Linux timer interval

Tags: timer, arduino, intel-edison

I want to run a timer with interval of 5 ms. I created a Linux timer and when a `sigalrm_handler` is called I'm checking elapsed time from a previous call. I'm getting times like: 4163, 4422, 4266, 4443, 4470 4503, 4288 microseconds when I want intervals to be about 5000 microseconds with a least possible error. I don't know why this interval is not constant but it varies and is much lower than it should be.

Here is my code:

```cpp
static int time_count;  
static int counter;  
struct itimerval timer={0};  


void sigalrm_handler(int signum)  
{  
  Serial.print("SIGALRM received, time: ");  
  Serial.println(micros()-time_count);  
  time_count=micros();  
}  


void setup() {  
  Serial.begin(9600);   
  timer.it_value.tv_sec = 1;  

  timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 5000;  

  signal(SIGALRM, &sigalrm_handler);  
  setitimer(ITIMER_REAL, &timer, NULL);  
  time_count = micros();  
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, what is the problem if you already get your timer working? BTW could you provide a minimal working hunk of code?

Comment: The interval is not constant. It varies and is much lower than 5000 microseconds.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to explain why that 5ms period matters so much to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to run a timer with interval of 5 ms.

You probably cannot get that period *reliably*, because it is smaller than a reasonable PC hardware can handle.

As a *rule of thumb*, 50 Hz (or perhaps 100Hz) is probably the highest *reliable* frequency you could get. And it is not a matter of software, but of hardware.

Think of your typical processor cache (a few megabytes). You could need a few milliseconds to fill it. Or think of time to handle a page fault; it probably would take more than a millisecond.

And Intel Edison is not a top-fast processor. I won't be surprised if converting a number to a string and displaying that string on some screen could take about a millisecond (but I leave you to check that). This could explain your figures.

Regarding software, see also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) (or consider perhaps some [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) approach *inside the kernel*; I don't recommend that).

Look also into `/proc/interrupts` several times (see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)) by running a few times some `cat /proc/interrupts` command in a shell. You'll probably see that the kernel gets interrupted less frequently than once every one or a few milliseconds.

BTW your signal handler calls non-async-signal-safe functions (so is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)). Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) & [signal-safety(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).

So it looks like your entire approach is wrong.

Maybe you want some [RTOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system), at least if you need some hard [real-time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_computing) (and then, you might consider upgrading your hardware to something faster and more costly).